# Is it difficult to factor a product of many large primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, prime-factorization

It's well known that it is difficult to factor a product of two large primes, and this fact is used in cryptography.

Is it also difficult to factor a product of $n$ large primes?

Comment: Yes, it is. Why should it be easier (except for $n=1$)?

Comment: A composite of two primes with $m$ digits is probably more difficult to factorise than a products of $k>2$ primes which also has $m$ digits, as you're more likely to find the relatively smaller primes faster. It's a bit like if I asked you to factorise 221 or 300. 300 is larger, and yet it's much easier to factorise because it has relatively smaller prime factors compared to 221.

Comment: Factoring a $10,000$ digit-number with $100$ distinct random prime factors with $90-110$ digits would be virtually hopeless in practice.

Comment: @Peter and yet it's still probably faster than factorising a $10,000$ digit number with two $5,000$ digit factors.

Comment: The running time of ECM depends mainly on the size of the second largest prime factor. The quadratic sieve has a running time only depending on the size of the input. Other methods only find factors in very special situations or with much luck. But $20-30$ digits are usually found fast with ECM, so factoring a number with $2,500$ digits with $100$ distinct random prime factors with $20-30$ digits would not take very long

Comment: @DanRust Not sure whether this is the case. I do not know the running times so precise to decide this

Comment: Finding one factor is easier because the probability that a prime factor $p$ has a special property that makes it easier to find, increases (e.g. if $p-1$ has small factors when using the Pollard method). A complete factorization is not easier, otherwise you could multiply a number that is the product of two primes that's hard to factor by many other known primes and then factor that larger number.

Comment: Pollard-rho is already virtually useless if you search for about $30$-digit-factors. The probability that $p-1$ (or $p+1$) has small factors is very small. It is true that occasionally much larger primes are found with Pollard-Rho, but usually the method only works for small factors